# Did anyone else find out about O'Neill kissing Carter?

Tags: stargate, stargate-sg1

In the "Window of Opportunity" episode, at one of the iterations, O'Neill resigns from the military, and when asked "why" he gleefuly exclaims "So I can do this", grabs Samantha Carter in a "[V-J Day in Times Square](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/V-J_Day_in_Times_Square)" display and kisses her.

[image: O'Neill kisses Sam]

As far as the rules for the groundhog day went, only O'Neill and Teal'c remembered the previous iterations.

**Did O'Neill or Teal'c ever reveal that kiss (to Sam or anyone else)?**

Comment: I don't think it mattered after what happened in the prior episode, [Divide and Conquer](http://stargate.wikia.com/wiki/Divide_and_Conquer)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The original script gives us a pretty good idea of the order of events;

> **JACK:** *Excuse me, George?*
>
> Jack checks his watch and hands Hammond a piece of paper.
>
> **HAMMOND:** *Colonel, what are you doing out of uniform?*
>
> **JACK:** *Handing you my resignation* [He hands a letter to Hammond]
>
> **SAM:** *You're resigning?! What for?*
>
> **JACK:** [looks at watch again] *So I can do... This!*
>
> [He takes her face in his hands, and kisses her on the mouth. She
>   starts to put her hand up as he puts his left hand around her neck.
>   His right hand is at the small of her back. He dips her, moving his
>   left hand to the side of her breast, and his right hand a little lower
>   ... Somewhere in the kiss, he slips her the tongue, (I think it's when
>   his face is turned right before he dips her) because she starts to
>   respond by putting her arms around his neck and the way their mouths
>   are moving, they are definitely kissing open-mouthed!
>
> [A blinding blue light appears]
>
> Light shines in Sam's face, making her blue eyes seem bluer. Sam's
>   looking around.
>
> **SAM:** *What are you smiling at?*
>   **JACK:** [smiling] *Nothin'*

Clearly he timed it so that the '[time loop](https://www.gateworld.net/sg1/s4/406.shtml)' would occur during or immediately after his attempt to kiss her, knowing full well that this was his opportunity to indulge a fantasy with no consequences.

Given that Teal'c **wasn't** in the room at the time, the only person who would know about the specific events would be him. The implication is that he doesn't plan to tell anyone. Certainly there are no canon instances of his discussing it with any of the *SG-1* team.

Comment: This is my favourite episode of  SG1. "IN THE MIDDLE OF MY BACKSWING?!" :')